# Bootstrap change navbar color

Tags: bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4, how do I go about changing the background color of a navbar? The code from twbscolor doesn't work. I want to make the background color a different color and the font color white.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-danger">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jordan Baron</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: i think you are missing `navbar-dark` as suggested in some answers. A quick code snippet at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900899/2797254

Answer (score 60):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

In terms of style, the Navbar hasn't changed a lot in Bootstrap 5. Therefore, changing/overriding the colors & styles is similar to Bootstrap 4. To customize the supported Navbar content styles...

```
/* change the background color */
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #4433cc;
}

/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #ffcc00;
}

/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffbb00;
}

/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:focus .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: pink;
}
```

If there are Navbar dropdowns you want to customize...

```
/* for dropdowns only */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ddaa11;
}

/* dropdown item text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-item {
    color: #000000;
}

/* dropdown item hover or focus */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-item:focus {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

**Bootstrap 4.x (update 2019)**

Remember that whatever CSS overrides you define **must be the same CSS specificity or greater** in order to properly override Bootstrap's CSS.

The Navbar is **transparent** by default. If you *only* want to change the background color, it can be done simply by applying the color to the `<navbar class="bg-custom">`, but remember that won't change the other colors such as the links, hover and dropdown menu colors.

Here's CSS that will change *any* relevant Navbar colors in Bootstrap 4...

```
/* change the background color */
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:focus .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/U9I2byZ3tS

---

**Override Navbar Light or Dark**

If you're using the Bootstrap 4 Navbar `navbar-light` or `navbar-dark` classes, then use this in the overrides. For example, changing the Navbar link colors...

```
.navbar-light .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-light .nav-item:focus .nav-link,
.navbar-light .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
}
```

---

When making any Bootstrap customizations, you need to understand **CSS Specificity**. Overrides in your custom CSS need to use selectors that are as specific as the bootstrap.css. [Read more](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-customize-bootstrap-b8078a011203)

---

**Transparent Navbar**

Notice that the Bootstrap 4 (and 5) Navbar is **transparent by default**. Use `navbar-dark` for dark/bold background colors, and use `navbar-light` if the navbar is a lighter color. This will effect the color of the text and [color of the toggler icon as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586729/bootstrap-4-change-hamburger-toggler-color/42587673#42587673).

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530995/171456

Answer (score 37):

**Update 2021 - Works for Bootstrap v5 & v4**

Here's a much more simple way to change the navbar background color.

Just use `.navbar-dark` instead of `.navbar-light` and add your custom background color class like `.bg-company-red`

`.navbar-dark` will make all your links white.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-company-red">
```

CSS style...

```
.bg-company-red {
    background-color: darkred !important;
}
```

See the following documentation link for your version:

- [Bootstrap v5 Navbar color schemes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes)
- [Bootstrap v4 Navbar color schemes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#color-schemes)

Comment: Hi! I'm using webpack for all my external css files. Once I try to override styles from Bootstrap 4 I must use `!important` rule, otherwise they are not applied. Does customization mechanism has changed in v4? With v3 I had no such problems

Comment: It's possible that you just need to be more specific in your CSS selector so that you don't need to use `!important`.  So instead of `.special-class` try `body > header > .special-class`.  Copy the selector that Bootstrap is using and then just make sure your override styles are included after the bootstrap styles.

Comment: Thanks for advice! I tried a lot of combinations, but only `important!` changes properties. Very weird situation...

Comment: Well, it was my fault: I had the `.bg-dark` class which already had `!important` rule. Removing it solved the problem

Comment: Using !important is a bad practice. More later or specific rule.

Answer (score 9):

I got it. This is very simple. Using the class `bg` you can achieve this easily.

Let me show you:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-full bg-primary"></nav>
```

This gives you the default blue `navbar`

If you want to change your favorite color, then simply use the style tag within the `nav`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-full" style="background-color: #FF0000">
```

Comment: While this may technically work, it's not the way to do it in Bootstrap and causes accessibility issues.

Answer (score 3):

you can write !important in front of background-color property value like this
it will change the color of links.

```
.nav-link {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Use of !important is not a good practice and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To change `navbar` background color:

```
.navbar-custom {

    background-color: yourcolor !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-danger">
```

So you have this code here, you must be knowing that `bg-danger` gives some sort of color.
Now if you want to give some custom color to your page then simply change `bg-danger` to `bg-color`.
Then either create a separate css-file or you can workout with `style` element in same `tag` .
Just do this-

```
`<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-color" style="background-color: cyan;">` .
```

That would do.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use "!important" to get your custom color

```
.navbar {
 background-color: yourcolor !important;
 }
```

Comment: Using !important is not a good practice when specificity can be used

Comment: Yes, you are correct we can add class to that element.