# Bootstrap 4 navbar-inverse doesn't have colour

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Recently I decided to try new bootstrap version (4). I did everything right with files (my html below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap 4 website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
    </nav>

    <!-- JS scripts here -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

but my navbar (navbar-inverse) has no colour. Have You ever seen something similar with Bootstrap 4?

Comment: I'm having the seem issue. got any leads on this?

Answer (score 11):

In Bootstrap 4 you want to change the background class the nav tag (.bg-light or .bg-dark).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark">
```

Next you can use `navbar-dark` to change the color of the text to fit the darker contrast.

Answer (score 2):

Navbar-inverse have property by default. It gives black color of navigation bar .
Just change the .navbar-defaultclass into .navbar-inverse

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
```

In bootstrap 4 navbar-inverse is replace by navbar-dark.
 The way it works is, you specify light or dark (via .navbar-light or .navbar-dark)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
```

Comment: You mean "navbar-inverse" instead of "navbar navbar-inverse"? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want black navbar then use class=" navbar-inverse " but if you want color of your choice then use css.

Comment: As I say class="navbar-inverse" doesn't work. Yes I want black color, but this class not only giving me any color at all but also removes padding from navbar.

Comment: Yeah, but the color of this navbar is blue :D I copied Your code :)

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Comment: what explanation did you need  ?

Comment: I need none, but the general audience might appreciate more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when upgrading to bootstrap4. 
You need to add `navbar-dark` to the `<nav>` tag indicating that this is a dark navbar so it should be using a white text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
    
    
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-expand-sm">
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer by @Asia-x3 helps a lot, but steel it does not change the forground color.
You can get the same layout as the previouse `navbar-inverse` by doing the following modification to the `<nav>` tag `class` property and adding `navbar-dark` after `bg-dark`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-4 has dropped inverse classes. Instead you can use:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

For more about Bootstrap 4, please visit:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/

For converting your V3 code to V4 try:
http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/