# bootstrap 4 (beta 2): navbar-default apparently removed, what now?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 3, the `navbar-default` class provided a linear-gradient background and a couple other nice touches. It seems to have been removed from Bootstrap 4 beta 2. Before re-creating the desired effect by hand I thought I might check here -- am I missing something?

Comment: ouch, downvote?! seems a bit harsh to me.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Bootstrap 4 docs.

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes

There is `navbar-dark bg-primary`, `navbar-light bg-light`, etc..

More info:
[Bootstrap 4 navbar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381596/bootstrap-4-navbar-color/43382283)
[Bootstrap 4 custom navbar](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-custom-navbar-1f6a2da5ed3c)

Comment: I assure you I did read the docs, and had I found the answer there I would not have asked here. The other two links are somewhat useful, thank you.