# Boostrap NavBar how to change text color on Navbar-Brand class?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried so many different options for the class to change the text color on the `navbar` and specifically the `navbar-brand` item. My `.navbar-brand color:purple;` css class is not functioning. Can you please help me figure out what I need to put as the tag so that I can change the color?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nicole Santarsiero</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">About &nbsp;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>

<style>

    .navbar-light {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
    color: purple;
    } 

</style>
```

Comment: it seems to work just fine for me! unless you mean something else check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamra/49Lh1wy8/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Learn about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). This tells the browser which CSS takes precedence when applying style to elements. You need to use a CSS selector that is the *same as*, or *more specific* than the Bootstrap 4 `.navbar-brand` selector which is:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
```

So, to *override* this you'd use:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: purple;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/D0dUL1I1rW

---

Also see:
[Bootstrap 4 navbar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381596/bootstrap-4-navbar-color)

Comment: This is a great answer. It’s better than all the official documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Plain CSS:

```
nav a { color: fuchsia; }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Plain css

```
nav a .navbar-brand { color: fuchsia; }
or
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

Comment: Hilarious. 4321

Answer (score 0):

**worked for me in bootstrap 4.5**

```
.navbar-brand{
color: blue !important;
}
```