# Bootstrap 4 Change nav link hover color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, themes

I am creating a website with `Bootstrap 4` and Sass (`scss`). The problem I am running into is the fact that the links in my nav are gray and not blue as I would like to have them.

Every topic I can find about this subject suggests to override the styling of the nav item. In my opinion this is going to bite you in the back later on when developing. So overriding the variable instead of the styling has my preference, but somehow it is not working correctly for me.

I have overridden the bootstrap styles via de recommended way:

- Create scss file with color overrides
- Change the styles via the `$theme-colors` function
- import the theme file before the `bootstrap.scss` file.

My `_theme.scss` is as follows:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

$blue:      #0053CB;
$blue-700:  #0F2C92;
$white:     #FFFFFF;
$green:     #39CA71;
$red:       #F1453D;
$orange:    #fd7e14;
$yellow:    #FDC02F;

$gray-100:  rgba(0,0,0,.03);

$theme-colors: (
  primary: $blue,
  secondary: $white,
  light: $white,
  dark: $blue-700,
  success: $green,
  warning: $orange,
  danger: $red,
);

// Import bootstrap as last so that the variables will be overridden
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

The bootstrap code for the `$link-hover-color` (is used for the nav-link) is as follows:

```
$link-color:                theme-color("primary") !default;
$link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
```

The problem is that the theme colors I defined are correctly used when using `bg-primary` in my html for example, but the hover and link colors are not the blue color I expected, they are gray, like the default. Is there something I a missing in my setup or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$link-color` and `$link-hover-color` affect links on the page, but not Navbar nav-links, which are specifically set via `$navbar-light-color` and/or `$navbar-dark-color` variables. These are defined using lightness/darkness of $black or $white as you can see in `variables.scss`.

Therefore, assuming you'd want blue (darker) links on a lighter background, you'd probably want to set the Navbar nav-link color as...

```
$navbar-light-color: rgba($primary, .5);
$navbar-light-hover-color: rgba($primary, .7);
$navbar-light-active-color: rgba($primary, .9);
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/66E7nUGVxD

---

The above is for SASS. You can still customize the Navbar with CSS only: [Bootstrap 4 navbar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381596/bootstrap-4-navbar-color)

Comment: If someone is looking for this in the drop-down menu, note that you need to look for the sass variables `$dropdown-*`