# unable to change navbar color in bootsrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I created a two navigation bars using bootstrap.

```html
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <link rel="style" href="css/main.css" />
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <title>Klevin's</title>
     </head>


          <body>


            <!-- ISLANDWIDE DELIVERY message -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-center" id="topmessage">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ISLANDWIDE DELIVERY</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Actual navigation bar -->
            <!-- A grey horizontal navbar that becomes vertical on small screens -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light" id="mainnavbar">

              <!-- Brand -->
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/ecommercewebsite/index.php">Klevin's</a>

              <!-- Links -->
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>

                <!-- Dropdown -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Shop
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Shoes</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Handbags</a>
                  </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>


              </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

then I wanted to change the background color of the second navigation bar. So I put following code in main css file

```
   body{
     padding-top: 50px;
   }

   #mainnavbar{
      background-color: #CC0000;
   }
```

But it doesn't change the color. I'm doing this according to this tutorial video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1phgYAzIfg&t=1066s
In his video it works correctly. But it doesn't work for me. I'm using a newer version of bootstrap. So not sure whether it is the reason.

Comment: uses `bg-color` to change the background color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `bg-light`. Since it uses an `!important` modifier it's overriding your CSS. You'll also want to use `navbar-dark` or `navbar-light` to give the [Navbar content (links) a light or dark color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381596/bootstrap-4-navbar-color/43382283#43382283).

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" id="mainnavbar"></nav>

   #mainnavbar{
      background-color: #CC0000;
   }
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/gFgVhhsoRP

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It seems like your answer is correct (according to the codeply)  . But it didn't solve my issue. May be the reason is <link> and <script> tags I have used in the header and the end of body area. This is the first time I creating a website. May be I have done something wrong in those link or scripts. I did it according to the video, w3school and bootstrap docs.

Comment: Finally I was able to do it like this   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" id="mainnavbar" style="background-color:#CC0000;">

Comment: Problem was in the <link rel="style" href="css/main.css" />

Comment: There was a typing error. I corrected it as <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" /> Now it is OK. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `bg-light` with `navbar-light`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" id="mainnavbar">
```