# how i style the same tag with multipal classes

Tags: html, css

I have this specific tag around 8 or 10 times in my code I want to edit the colour of the word in  between  the colour white but the double class system is not working for me the tag already has a nave-link class and then I added the navi class to edit it,I do not know to solve this problem one approach is to style those  a million times manually I am pasting the code of index.html and style.css

PS: I almost forgot to mention I am using bootstrap for my project so this is the code in between the nav ie navigation bar

**this is the html code**

```
 <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link navi" href="index.html">
           Home
       </a>
 </li>
```

**and this is the css code**

```
.navi
{
    color:#fdfefe;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381596/bootstrap-4-navbar-color)

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple classes the later ones override the earlier ones.

```css
.first {
    color:red;
}
.second {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<p class="first second">yo</p>
```

This will result in a green text