# A link won't hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a nav bar and I would like for the a links to change color when I hover over them but for some reason, even though I used the :hover selector, it still won't work. Can anyone please help me?

```
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark static-top my-navbar my-navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <button`enter code here`
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarResponsive"
            aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                  >Home
                  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link my-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

This is my CSS:

```
/* --- Navbar --- */

.my-navbar {
  background: rgba(116, 118, 119, 0.5);
}

ul li a {
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
}
/* --- Navbar End --- */
```

Comment: I should also mention that I can't change the text colour either in the "ul li a" css block.

Comment: First remove from your code in **<button`enter code here`**  remove `enter code here` this

Comment: no, sorry, that's a bug in post when I formatted the text.  In my code there's no "enter-code-here:

Comment: At 4th line in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change link color and hover color in Bootstrap version 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573324/how-can-i-change-link-color-and-hover-color-in-bootstrap-version-4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625972/change-color-of-bootstrap-navbar-on-hover-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap try putting ' ! important ' in the css code.
!important property in CSS means that all subsequent rules on an element are to be ignored, and the rule denoted by !important is to be applied. This rule overrides all previous styling rules ​-- the !important property increases its priority.

Your css code :

```
.my-navbar {
   background: rgba(116, 118, 119, 0.5) ! important;
}

ul li a {
    font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif ! important;
}

a:hover {
     color: black ! important;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid the `!important` unless there is realy no other way to do the job.

Comment: I know !important is not good practice however Bootsrap is very stubborn. I only needed it for the hover effect. Thank you very much, I have left you an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `navbar-dark` you have to be very specific in your selector.
For example this will do the job with a `.navbar-dark.my-navbar` without space.

```
.navbar-dark.my-navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-dark.my-navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Edit** You mentioned below that you've removed the`navbar-dark`. In that case you may style the hamburger button with these selectors. Use the colors you like.

```
/* the button */
.my-navbar .navbar-toggler {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* the icon in the button - change only 0, 0, 0, 0.5 (rgba color) */
.my-navbar .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 0.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Comment: It works if I do it that way however now the hamburger button is gone when I resize the page

Comment: The `navbar-expand-lg` in your html is the switch between hamburger or normal menu.

Comment: This is really great :) upvote it because `!important` not choice if other way available

Comment: So what should I do with navbar-expand-lg? Because if I get rid of navbar-dark, I can customize my a links but the hamburger button disappears when I resize the screen

Comment: To set another point where the hamburger (dis)appears, change the last 2 letters in `navbar-expand-lg`. Possible values are -sm -md -lg -xl

Comment: I did change my post with an example to change the hamburger button..